# having one column related to 2 different fields in another table in access?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-design, relational-database

I am building an access database for air freight for my company.  I have a table with all the airports, and I have another table with air freight costs.  The following are my fields for each table (a * means that it is part of a key)

tblAirports

- AirportID*(Autonumber)
- AirportCode(Text - 3 letter IATA code)
- AirportCity(Number - connects to a cities table)

tblAirFreight

- OriginAirport* (Number - connects to tblAirports)
- DestAirport* (Number - connects to tblAirports)
- Company* (Number - connects to a table of companies)
- 50 kgs.
- 100 kgs.
- 500 kgs.

Air freight is connected to the airport table with referential integrity on both origin and destination services.

Right now, not even a straightforward select query will work on the air freight table.  I want to type in an origin airport code (SEA, JFK, etc.) and/or destination airport code, and the query to return the corresponding rates for air freight.  How do I do this?

Comment: could you elaborate this please "Right now, not even a straightforward select query will work on the air freight table". Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get the airport details for each of the airport columns in the freight table so you just join to the airports table twice. then you filter based on the parameters supplied. This is only rough to point you in the right direction, you will probably need to play with the where clause a bit.

```
select *
from 
    tblAirFreight f
    inner join tblAirports o
        on o.AirportID = f.OriginAirport
    inner join tblAirports d
        on d.AirportID = f.DestAirport
where 
    (f.OriginAirport = @YourOriginAirport or isnull(@YourOriginAirport) = 1)
    and (f.DestAirport = @YourDestAirport or isnull(@YourDestAirport) = 1)
```